# TypeError com campo calculado (Django)

Tags: django

TypeError com campo calculado

```
unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'int' and 'NoneType'
```

erro na linha do return abaixo

models.py

```
def get_subtotal(self):
    return self.price_sale * self.quantity

subtotal = property(get_subtotal)
```

admin.py

```
class SaleDetailInline(admin.TabularInline):
    list_display = ['product', 'quantity', 'price_sale', 'subtotal']
    readonly_fields = ['subtotal', ]
    model = SaleDetail
    extra = 0
```

Na view o subtotal funciona, mas no Admin não.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Esse erro está ocorrendo porque você está tentando multiplicar um inteiro por um tipo vazio.

**Exemplo:**

```
>>> price_sale = None
>>> quantity = 2
>>> print price_sale * quantity

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'int' and 'NoneType'
```

Você pode corrigir dessa forma:

```
def get_subtotal(self):
    try:
        return self.price_sale * self.quantity
    except TypeError:
        return 0
```

ou:

```
def get_subtotal(self):
    if self.price_sale and self.quantity:
        return self.price_sale * self.quantity
    else:
        return 0
```

Comment: Então o que sugere: (price_sale * quantity) or 0  ?

Comment: @RegisdaSilva editei a resposta e adicionei as soluções

Comment: Uma forma simples é usar o `or`: `return self.price_sale * (self.quantify or 0)`

Comment: @drgarcia1986 se `self.price_sale` for igual `None` ocorrerá erro, o certo é verificar ambas as variáveis e não só o `self.quantity`.

Comment: Tem razão, não posso considerar que o campo `self.price_sale` tem valor.